# Ubuntu upstart service hangs

Tags: upstart

I am trying to have the jenkins java application run at startup, run as the jenkins user. I have a upstart conf file located at /etc/init/jenkins.conf with the following inside it.

```
description "Jenkins daemon"

start on startup
stop on shutdown

task

setuid jenkins
setgid jenkins
java -jar /usr/local/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war
```

Running service jenkins start just hangs.  I have tried numerous combinations of upstart internals but cannot find a collection that works, it hangs every time.  Is there any error reporting anywhere that I can look at to see what is going wrong?  Logged in as the jenkins user I can start the application with that java command.

Comment: Have you tried providing the full path to the `java` executable? why not use a lightweight container and the jenkins war? Odds are the container provides an `init.d` or `upstart` script already.